# JQuery Slider Gallery Problem

Tags: jquery

I am trying to implment the SliderGallery which is a 1.2.6 JQuery Plugin

http://jqueryfordesigners.com/slider-gallery/

This is not functioning in my JSFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/NinjaSk8ter/CKSxe/

I believe that I have a mistake in the JavaScript setup w/in JSFiddle.

Does anyone see where I went wrong?

Comment: @suhair Yes I deleted that Fiddle by mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one
http://jsfiddle.net/8gUUZ/8/

I just used the jquery load function instead of window' load

Comment: I knew it was a problem with the JavaScript, thank you for that!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the window.onload. You can chang it to $(document).ready();

http://jsfiddle.net/ynhat/8gUUZ/9/